# Mat Tree Angular material with ngrx store as datasource

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material, ngrx

I've try to connect Mat Tree with my store under ngrx, but i have a lot a problems.
Starting with https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-dynamic  i would like to change the current datasource with my store ; i want take data from    store at first and second level of tree and for ulteriors nested level i would like to check if are already load into store otherwise i need to load them from API request (then saved into store).
There are any example for something like this? or can someone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

###### Old version below.

Instead of using a [NestedTreeControl](https://v7.material.angular.io/cdk/tree/api#NestedTreeControl), I used a [FlatTreeControl](https://v7.material.angular.io/cdk/tree/api#FlatTreeControl) and provided a flat List of nodes as dataSource. And instead of using the mechanics of the library for loading data, I managed it via the store and actions. So the `<mat-tree ...>` gets just a flat observable list as dataSource, and the store controls, how and when this list is modified.
So basically the `mat-tree` is used just for representation and the behaviour of data-management is done in the store.

```
export class MyTreeComponent {
    nodes$: Observable<NodeModel[]>;
    treeControl: FlatTreeControl<NodeModel>;

    constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
        this.nodes$ = this.store.pipe(select(nodes));

        // tree control params are "getLevel: node => number" and "isExpandable: node => boolean"
        this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<NodeModel>(node => node.level, node => node.isExpandable);
    }

    onExpandNode(node: NodeModel) {
        this.store.dispatch(expandNode({ node.id });
    }
}

<mat-tree [dataSource]="nodes$" [treeControl]="flatTreeControl">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
        <div (click)="onExpandNode(node)">{{ node.label }}</div>
    </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

###### This part of the answer is obsolete and is just for transparency here.

I implemented a DataSource, wich takes a callback as constructor parameter. In my tree-component I instantiate the `TreeControl` and the `DataSource`. Via the callback, I can emit/dispatch expand and collapse actions against the store. 
I'm curious, what your solution was.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.scss']
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  nestedTreeControl: NestedTreeControl<Node>;
  dataSource: MyNestedTreeDataSource;
  
  // alternatively inject the store in the constructor
  // and dispatch the action directly in the callback
  @Output()
  expandNode = new EventEmitter<Node>();
  
  constructor() {
    this.nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Node>(this._getChildren);
    this.dataSource = new MyNestedTreeDataSource(this.nestedTreeControl, this.onExpandNode.bind(this));
  }
  
  onExpandNode(node: Node): void {
    this.expandNode.emit(node);
  }
  
  private _getChildren = (node: Node) => of(node.children);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a gist or stackblitz of your implementation?

Comment: Your answer is interesting and would help me to solve a problem too... but without the source of MyNestedTreeDataSource it's just useless... would you mind to share it?

Comment: Hi @GeraldChifanzwa and @user:252092, sorry for my late reply. I took a look in my repository and tried to get behind it again. I changed the answer accordingly and hope, that it is now more useful. In the end, I had to change from a `NestedTree` to a `FlatTree` and manually take control over the data-loading and click-events.